SQL Server on Linux - Error while loading libraries
I'm trying to install SQL Server on Linux.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed on WSL 2.
I try to start SQL Server with the following command:
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
I get the following error message:
shandloff@MYCOMPUTER:/usr/lib$ /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried creating a symbolic link with the following:
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libssl.so libssl.so.1.1

I verified the link exists with the following commands:
cd /usr/lib
ls -l libssl*

This produced the following output:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 30 12:48 libssl.so.1.1 -> libssl.so
I'm still getting the same error. Not sure how to proceed.

Did you follow the Quickstart: Install SQL Server and create a database on Ubuntu guide?

MS doesn't support WSL as an installation target for SQL Server.
[link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2004

@Ronaldo I did follow the instructions

@RiteshChawla I thought that was only for WSL 1. I'll re-read it and see if that's the end of the matter.

@SamuelHandloff Sure, the MS article doesn't distinguish on the version of WSL. So I assume it is for both WSL 1 and 2, though I haven't tested with WSL 2 personally. I currently run a virtualbox Ubuntu 22.04 VM where I have sql server installed and runs fine.

@RiteshChawla I was under the impression that WSL 2 was closer to a true linux install. But you are probably right. Thanks

@SamuelHandloff sure, hope that helped.
